# How Transform animation works?

Tags: manim

I am trying to understand how manim **automatically** figures out how to smoothly transform, say, a `Circle()` into `Square()`?

Is this a common pattern? Is Manim unique in this respect or are there similar libraries which do the same magic? I am interested in figuring out how to create manim animations for iOS without running python.

Comment: No it is not unique.  You might want to mention what languages you are familiar with.  I mean, https://github.com/veltman/flubber is some source code in js, but this is common enough that there will be examples in languages you are familiar with.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for! I am specifically looking for C++ or Swift implementation, but even this JavaScript code is a great start. Which keywords I should look for?

Comment: I just googled shape morphing I think

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to explain all the math behind it, just an outline so you can learn on your own.

In Manim, every curve that you generate (circles, squares, etc.) is a Bezier Curve, these curves have very special properties and are widely used in multimedia and graphic design software.

The transformations are essentially interpolations between Bezier curves, that is, if you want to transform a circle into a square, what Manim does is take those Bezier curves and interpolate between them using an algorithm.

Learn [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) Bezier curves.